# PHP:Uploading to wrong folder. How to change it to get it in to right place?

Tags: php, image, upload

I want to Upload picture to my web server.

```
$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
```

The code above would add my picture to folder like this:

```
www.something.com/admin/upload
```

How could I get my file to the correct folder:

```
www.something.com/upload
```

As you see, it should go one forder back.

The complety code is found on:

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/file_upload.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$newname = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../upload').'/'.$filename;
```